# How can I get a real IP using adb command? (not Local IP)

Tags: android, adb, ip-address

I am using Galaxy Samsung s4 lte-a
Android version is 5.0.1

I can get the Local IP address via "adb shell netcfg"
Then IP will come out like 10.236.36.137

But, if I check the IP on sites such as Google or whatismyaddress, I get 211.238.10.135
The IP address obtained using adb is different from the IP address displayed on the google or whatismyipaddress

Is there a formula for converting to real IP(211.238.10.135) using Local IP(10.236.36.137)?

I want to get real ip addresss(211.238.10.135) using adb command.
How can I get that ip?

Comment: You mean the IP that identifies the device into the internet?

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv yes, I want to get the ip address using adb command. The ip address obtained from "adb shell netcfg" is different from my connection IP displayed on Google site.

Comment: Your "real" (visible) IP address depends on who is looking at you-- if they're on the same network, a different one, you or they are behind a proxy or firewall, etc. The only way to know it is to ask them what it is. At least, for IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

Android is first a Linux based Operating System, and with adb shell you can run most of the commands you can run on Linux. Tested on Android 10, for example, try:

```
bloom$ adb shell curl ident.me
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    12  100    12    0     0     65      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    6584.71.214.38
```

aside the terrible formatting, guess what, 84.71.214.38 is exactly my public ip address, as I could verify on [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com)

check the `curl` command manual or similar for more info.